# How do the credentials work in gRPC .NET?

Tags: c#, grpc

I am trying to understand how the authentication with SSL credentials works.

[This is the documentation for service.](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/grpc/authn-and-authz/sample/Ticketer/Startup.cs)

[This is the documentation for the client.](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/grpc/authn-and-authz/sample/TicketerClient/Program.cs)

The client sends a request for authentication to the service, the service generates a token that is sent to the client. Then the client can authenticate and can call the service.

If this is correct, I don't see where is the security here, because any application can request a token to the service and then can call. There are no SSL certificates to can authenticate.

At least if I use self-signed certificates created with OpenSSL for example, the client application can use the client certificate and only this application can call the service. If another application, which has no client certificate, tries to call the service, it will not be successful.

Here there is another problem, how to store in a safe way the certificate in the client application, but this is another problem. Now I am trying to understand how the security works in the case the service generates and sends the token to the client.

Comment: The secret token would only ever be send on an encrypted SSL connection. 1. The client connect to a server and verifies its talking to the right server by checking it against it trust roots (every http client capable of SSL/TLS has those). 2. the encrypted connection is setup using a handshake where parties exchange public keys and choose a secret session key that is used to encrypt the connection. 3. the client now has a connection to a trusted server and the connection is encrypted. It's safe to send secrets on that connection (e.g. auth tokens) since no one else than server can read them

Comment: https://github.com/jtattermusch/grpc-authentication-kubernetes-examples